# Number of factors of a big number

Tags: combinatorics, factoring, prime-factorization

How to find the number of factors of $884466000$ without using a calculator?

Comment: That one is small and easy. You can immediately see a $2^4$, a $5^3$ and an $11$. A short look also shows a $3^2$, and you're left with $4467$. Oh, that yields a further $3$ (wasn't obvious before, to me at least), leaving $1489$. That is prime.

Comment: if the number is 43562153896.I want to know the number of factors only

Comment: That one's not so easily doable in my head, so I let the machine factor it. $32$ divisors.

Comment: The point of the answers is that there is a simple formula based on the prime factorization.  Without the factorization, you can't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too difficult to factor, since it's divisible by rather high powers of $2$ and $5$; right off the bat, we see that

$$884466000 = 1000 \cdot 884466 = 1000 \cdot 2 \cdot 442233$$

Now $442233$ has digit sum $4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 = 18$, so it's divisible by $9$, giving

$$442233 = 49137 \cdot 9 = 16379 \cdot 27$$

Looking back at the original form of the number, it's also clearly divisible by $11$, since $$442233 = 11 \cdot 40203$$

So summarizing what we've got so far,

$$884466000 = 2^4 5^3 3^3 11^1 \cdot 1489$$

Now finally, $\sqrt{1489} < 40$, and checking the primes between $13$ and $37$, we find no more divisors. Hence $1489$ is prime.

---

Thus, every factor of $884466000$ is of the form

$$2^a 3^b 5^c 11^d 1489^e$$

with $0 \le a \le 4$, $0 \le b, c, \le 3$, and $0 \le d, e\le 1$, for a total of $5 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 2^2$ divisors.

Comment: if the number is 43562153896

Comment: I want to know the number of factors only

Comment: First you have to find the prime factorization. Let $N$ be your number, with prime factorization $N = p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \ldots p_n^{r_n}$. Then every factor is $N$ is of the form $p_1^{s_1} p_2^{s_2} \ldots p_n^{s_n}$ with $0 \leq s_i \leq r_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. So for every $s_i$ we have $r_i + 1$ choices, and the number of factors is $(r_1 + 1)(r_2 + 1) \ldots (r_n + 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

First, divide it by 1000, and you get 884466. Since it seems divisible by 2 and 11, divide it by 22, and you get 40203. Since the sum of digits is a multiple of 9, divide it by 9, and you get 4467. Its sum is a multiple of 3, so divide it by 3, and you get 1489. Unfortunately, 1489 is a prime number, so the factor of the given number is $2^4 \times 3^3 \times 5^3 \times 11 \times 1489$.

Comment: if the number is 819529

Comment: I want to know the number of factors only